# In Excel, how do I generate a copy a row X number of times?

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel, I need to generate files for bulk uploads, which will contain 1K, 5K, 10K, and 100K of lines.  So I looked in VBA script. Here's on :

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

    ' This routing will copy rows based on the quantity to a new sheet.
    Dim rngSinglecell As Range
    Dim rngQuantityCells As Range
    Dim intCount As Integer

    ' Set this for the range where the Quantity column exists. This works only if there are no empty cells
    Set rngQuantityCells = Range("D1", Range("D1").End(xlDown))

    For Each rngSinglecell In rngQuantityCells
        ' Check if this cell actually contains a number
        If IsNumeric(rngSinglecell.Value) Then
            ' Check if the number is greater than 0
            If rngSinglecell.Value > 0 Then
                ' Copy this row as many times as .value cut out rngSinglecell DOT Value
                For intCount = 1 To 1000
                    ' Copy the row into the next emtpy row in sheet2
                    Range(rngSinglecell.Address).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                    ' The above line finds the next empty row.

                Next
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

But what I want to do, is to copy a row of data that goes from `A15` to `Y15` , and just paste it into a worksheet, so that I can copy-paste it back to the original worksheet (used for bulk upload in iProcurement ).

For some reason, my row is only getting copied twice, even though I changed intcount to the following :

```
For intCount = 1 To 1000
```

any tips appreciated, thanks !

Comment: You are copying it 1000 times over the same output row.

Comment: You want to copy it as many times as the cell in column D specifies?

Comment: @RBarryYoung -  Ok, I will study this again , thanks !

Comment: @Raystafarian - Not sure I'm seeing what you mean. What's column D for > ?

Comment: You specify column D. I'm not sure what your intent is with this macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell you're trying to do this -

```
Sub test()
    ' This routing will copy rows based on the quantity to a new sheet.

    Dim lastrow As Integer
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Set this for the range where the Quantity column exists. This works only if there are no empty cells

    Dim destlastrow As Integer
    destlastrow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ' The above line finds the next empty row.
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        ' Check if this cell actually contains a number
        If IsNumeric(Cells(i, 4)) Then
            ' Check if the number is greater than 0
            If Cells(i, 4) > 0 Then
                ' Copy this row as many times as .value cut out rngSinglecell DOT Value
                For j = 1 To Cells(i, 4).Value
                    ' Copy the row into the next emtpy row in sheet2
                    Cells(i, 4).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(destlastrow, 1)
                    destlastrow = destlastrow + 1

                Next
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```